# What are the names of these Characters?

Tags: gate-keepers

If am not mistaken this anime was aired in 90's, I forgot their names and the title of it.
I tried so many times to search this on google, but I failed.
I really want know their names and also the title of it.I remembered that this anime was based on a period time of japan.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anime is [Gate Keepers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_Keepers)

You can find the list of characters with pictures [here](http://gatekeeperaegis.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Gatekeeper_characters). They are in order from left to right:

Shun Ukiya - Ruriko Ikusawa - Misao Sakimori - Reiko Asagiri - Kaoru Konoe

Answer (score 1):

That's from the anime [Gate Keepers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_Keepers)